# How can I get a unique ID for multiple USB devices (cameras) for WebRTC (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, usb, webrtc

I am developing on a Windows machine but the target platform is a Raspberry Pi using Chromium (this is optional, any browser is fine).  I am connecting multiple cameras (say a dozen) to the Pi and will obviously even have to use USB hubs. In the code below, I appear to get different Device IDs each time I plug in a camera or even in a new browser session. I need to be able to record from a specific camera, record video or an image, turn the camera on/off etc. but I can't do that unless I can get some kind of unique identifier for each camera.

I could also use the video feed identifiers perhaps to identify the camera (e.g. /dev/video0, /dev/video1, ... /dev/video*n*), but not sure how to do that in the browser.

html:

```
<div id="container">
   <h1>Test  Page</h1>
   <div id="List"></div>
   <div class="select">
      <p><label for="videoSource">Video source: </label><select id="videoSource"></select></p>
      <p><label for="audioOutput">audioOutput source: </label><select id="audioOutput"></select></p>
      <p><label for="audioInput">audioInput source: </label><select id="audioInput"></select></p>
   </div>
   <video muted autoplay></video>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    var DeviceInfo = "";
    var videoSelect = document.getElementById("videoSource");
    var audioOutputSelect = document.getElementById("audioOutput");
    var audioInputSelect = document.getElementById("audioInput");
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(gotDevices)
      .catch(errorCallback);
    function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
        alert("deviceInfos.length: " + deviceInfos.length);
        for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
            var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
            DeviceInfo += "<br>=================";
            for (var key in deviceInfo) {
                DeviceInfo += "<br>" + key + " => " + deviceInfo[key];
            }
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
            if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
                option.text = deviceInfo.label ||
                'Microphone ' + (audioInputSelect.length + 1);
                audioInputSelect.appendChild(option);
            } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audiooutput') {
                option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Speaker ' +
                (audioOutputSelect.length + 1);
                audioOutputSelect.appendChild(option);
            } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
                option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' +
                (videoSelect.length + 1);
                videoSelect.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("List").innerHTML = DeviceInfo;
    }
    function errorCallback(err) {
        alert(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    }
</script>
```

Sample Output:

```
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => 68KeeWjqTyTiECj/vjwuwWSMNXraaUu/sz5CDSnbNg0=
kind => videoinput
label =>
groupId =>
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => wuJ0e0dyB7bUyO3L6MHV6CD8v+FQRRZ0V9oSS/IMebg=
kind => videoinput
label =>
groupId =>
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => BdtXeGDVhh2g68rfu4cOg9yZoS7WdgTNr8nXOThLfPU=
kind => videoinput
label =>
groupId =>
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => mAc/SogzkQKpq8O3Zto64+SlOwsg1kKdXJLxua5t328=
kind => audioinput
label =>
groupId =>
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => n1or62DRNYW0zC4yQVox75nQhBZb0BYR9C/VWB1GLkM=
kind => audioinput
label =>
groupId =>
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => 74K5qAhhroD8esqAYW+9P8jxs4yvdWnPQ1Ia8OYJZqc=
kind => audioinput
label =>
groupId =>
=================
toJSON => function toJSON() { [native code] }
deviceId => rHIqRAFL4ZcfTqJc214llo5XxeDLm+pTG/DoicpOryM=
kind => audioinput
label =>
groupId =>
```

Notice also that label is blank (Windows/Firefox) but in Raspbian/Chromium I do get labels.  Unfortunately they are not unique (e.g. USB2.0 Camera (1871:0142)) If I were somehow able to use these labels... This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo) says label "Returns a DOMString that is a label describing this device (for example "External USB Webcam"). Only available during active MediaStream use or when persistent permissions have been granted." I have no idea what or how to do "persistent permissions".

Any help appreciated. And I am willing to use a different technology, i.e. fswebcam somehow linked to the browser (custom URL) or php or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The [`deviceId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo/deviceId) is that id. It's unique to the page's origin for privacy reasons, yet it will be persisted across browsing sessions like a cookie, after the first time either camera or microphone permission has been granted once to a page from your origin. After that, it should persist until the user clears their cookies.

In other words, if the user has ever granted `getUserMedia` access to your page in the past, be it yesterday or a year ago, then ids you get now will match what they were then, in pages from your origin, provided the user hasn't cleared their cookies since then.

The `label` field is also blank until you've done this, again for privacy reasons.

Unplugging and re-plugging devices shouldn't matter. The ids should still be usable.

Comment: Thanx @jib but the ids do change so how can they be reused? The Pi may reboot and then we have to reprogram everything to use the new IDs.

Comment: @Chiwda I would isolate the problem then. The ids are supposed to be stored in cookie-like storage. Does it work in a regular desktop browser for you? If so then there's a bug in your raspberry pi version. Does it have storage? Worst case, use the labels as others have suggested (they also require gUM success first, as I mention).

Comment: They (IDs) work the same on Windows 10 and the Pi.  Yes, I understand they need a successful getUsermedia(), but that by definition means they are recreated each time it is called.

Comment: @Chiwda No, what I mean is: if the user has ever granted `getUserMedia` access to your page *in the past*, be it yesterday or a year ago, then ids you get now will be consistent with what they were then, *in pages from your origin*. The user can reset this logic only by clearing their cookies.

Comment: Even if that were the case, it doesn't help because I need them to consistent across users. No matter who arrives at that page, they should get the right video camera.

Comment: @Chiwda Then use the `label`. You might also want to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had a similar problem. When you boot up a pi with attached USB cameras, they show up as /dev/video0,video1,video2 etc.

The trouble is that on reboot the camera that was video0 may become video2 as they shuffle around. Sounds a bit like your problem.

I have figured out how to give each camera an address that reflects only which USB hole it is plugged into, regardless of which videox it is. Works for cameras that all have the same serial number even.

when I invoke fswebcam -d $realpath /dev/camUSB1 fred.jpg it always uses the same camera no matter what videox it has been assigned.

If you have solved this problem already (I hope so) then I will leave it at that. If not I will explain what has to be done to tie the cameras to specific USB sockets.

Comment: I am facing this issue with my USB camera and I am looking for a solution for my Jetson Nano but fswebcam doesn't work there. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

OK - here goes - I would post a bit of code that does all this, but I don't understand the site rules .. so I will just describe it.

The aim is to end with with an identifier that corresponds to a USB bus address regardless of the video number. Put all that into a udev file and activate it

The process ..

Run fswebcam repeatedly to collect a list of valid video numbers. I found that most camera models were video0,1,2... but some did video0,2,4,..

Now - for each video number videoX

Issue the command

udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/videoX > wwx
(or whatever video number)

this generates a screed of stuff into wwx (or whatever else you want to call the file)

find/extract (from wwx) the line that says "KERNELS==1-1.3" or something like that - the bit after the '==' is the usb bus address for video0 ...

now generate a line that says
"KERNEL=="videoX",SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux","KERNELS==1.1.3",SYMLINK+="xx"

Make a list of these lines. Then sort the list on the KERNELS== field.

After sorting go down the list and replace xx with CAMUSB1,CAMUSB2, .....

End of process

Now you have a udev file (I call mine cam.rules) - put it in /etc/udev/rule.d, run udevadm trigger and job is done

here is a real cam.rules (these cameras connected as video0,2,4,6 ....)

KERNEL=="video0",SUBSYSTEM="video4linux",KERNELS=="1.1.3:1.0",SYMLINK+="camUSB1"
KERNEL=="video2",SUBSYSTEM="video4linux",KERNELS=="1-1.1.1:1.0",SYMLINK+="camUSB2"
KERNEL=="video4",SUBSYSTEM="video4linux",KERNELS=="1-1.1.3:1.0",SYMLINK+="camUSB3"
KERNEL=="video6",SUBSYSTEM="video4linux",KERNELS=="1-1.1.4:1.0",SYMLINK+="camUSB4"

Now fswebcam -d $realpath CAMUSB1 ... will always give you the same camera no matter what videoX it has been allocated etc etc and it persists through reboots because USB bus addresses persist through reboots.  And of course You don't have to call it camUSBx - use any name.

I have an RPi python 2.7 program that does all this. I have been running it for a couple of years now. You are welcome to it if I can find out how to pass it on. I have no experience with github - sorry

Answer (score -1):

It may be security issue for browsers to maintain same deviceid, websites can track user by using deviceid something like browser cookie.

You can get the device vendor name from [deviceInfo](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/devices/input-output/js/main.js#L40) label or MediaTrack label, if all are from same vendor, then poke [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/WRWSBLhK2y8). Or dig [chromium devices](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=enumerateDevices&type=cs) and build your custom version.